# Union two select statements while keeping distinct for not null column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, union

My Oracle statement has two parts:

Select statement 1 is returning rows as:

```
a  b  c  NULL

a  x  y  NULL
```

Select statement 2 is returning rows as:

```
a  b  c  d

e  f  g  h
```

I want to union both the selects provided for a row having same columns(except NULL column) as in select 2 , only the not NULL row is returned.
Output:

```
a  b  c  d

a  x  y  NULL

e  f  g  h
```

**CHANGED REQUIREMENTS**:

The requirements are bit changed now and i have case like:

Select statement 1 as:

```
a b c e NULL

a x y s NULL
```

Select statement 2 as:

```
a b c d text

e f g h text
```

Output:

```
a b c d text

a x y s NULL

e f g h text
```

I.e. in case of NULL field in last column, I need to fetch the row from "Select statement 2".

Comment: So what do you expect as result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that first three columns are not nullable you can use `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
with t1 as (
select 'a' c1, 'b' c2, 'c' c3, null c4 from dual
union all
select 'a', 'x', 'y', null from dual),
t2 as (
select 'a' c1, 'b' c2, 'c' c3, 'd' c4 from dual
union all
select 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h' from dual)
 select c1, c2, c3, coalesce(t1.c4, t2.c4) c4 
  from t1 full outer join t2 using(c1, c2, c3);

C1 C2 C3 C4
-- -- -- --
a  b  c  d
e  f  g  h
a  x  y (NULL)
```

**According to updated requirements**:

```
with t1(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) as (
select 'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', null from dual
union all
select 'a', 'x', 'y', 's', null from dual),
t2(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) as (
select 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'qwerty' from dual
union all
select 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'asdfgh' from dual)
select c1,
       c2,
       c3,
       nvl(nvl2(t1.c5, t1.c4, t2.c4), t1.c4) c4,
       coalesce(t1.c5, t2.c5) c5
  from t1
  full outer join t2
 using (c1, c2, c3);

C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
-- -- -- -- ------
a  b  c  d  qwerty
e  f  g  h  asdfgh
a  x  y  s  (NULL)
```

This is fast and dirty hack. Although it works on sample data you provided, it might behave unpredictable on your full dataset. This just gives you an idea how to accomplish your goal. I strongly recommend you to test it thoroughly before use.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Yaroslav, But in my case i am getting all rows with null and not null fields. It is not picking t1.c4 as null i guess.   Please comment

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that we got `TABLE1` and `TABLE2`, in this query `TAB1` returns same rows in tables and remove the null columns from that rows and `TAB2` returns all rows from `TABLE1` with out the rows which are the same with the rows in `TABLE2` and `TAB3` is same `TAB2` but the tables changed, and finally UNION ALL TAB1 and TAB2 and TAB3:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 
CASE WHEN T1.COL1 IS NULL THEN T2.COL1 ELSE T1.COL1 END COL1,
CASE WHEN T1.COL2 IS NULL THEN T2.COL2 ELSE T1.COL2 END COL2,
CASE WHEN T1.COL3 IS NULL THEN T2.COL3 ELSE T1.COL3 END COL3,
CASE WHEN T1.COL4 IS NULL THEN T2.COL4 ELSE T1.COL4 END COL4
FROM 
TABLE2 T2 INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON 
(T1.COL1 = T2.COL1 OR T1.COL1 IS NULL OR T2.COL1 IS NULL) AND 
(T1.COL2 = T2.COL2 OR T1.COL2 IS NULL OR T2.COL2 IS NULL) AND 
(T1.COL3 = T2.COL3 OR T1.COL3 IS NULL OR T2.COL3 IS NULL) AND 
(T1.COL4 = T2.COL4 OR T1.COL4 IS NULL OR T2.COL4 IS NULL))TAB1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM TABLE1
MINUS
SELECT T1.*
FROM 
TABLE2 T2 INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON 
(T1.COL1 = T2.COL1 OR T1.COL1 IS NULL OR T2.COL1 IS NULL) AND 
(T1.COL2 = T2.COL2 OR T1.COL2 IS NULL OR T2.COL2 IS NULL) AND 
(T1.COL3 = T2.COL3 OR T1.COL3 IS NULL OR T2.COL3 IS NULL) AND 
(T1.COL4 = T2.COL4 OR T1.COL4 IS NULL OR T2.COL4 IS NULL))TAB2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM TABLE2
MINUS
SELECT T2.*
FROM 
TABLE2 T2 INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON 
(T1.COL1 = T2.COL1 OR T1.COL1 IS NULL OR T2.COL1 IS NULL) AND 
(T1.COL2 = T2.COL2 OR T1.COL2 IS NULL OR T2.COL2 IS NULL) AND 
(T1.COL3 = T2.COL3 OR T1.COL3 IS NULL OR T2.COL3 IS NULL) AND 
(T1.COL4 = T2.COL4 OR T1.COL4 IS NULL OR T2.COL4 IS NULL))TAB3;
```

### [SQL Fiddle1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e828b/1)

### [SQL Fiddle2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e828b/2)